# Got macbook air fixed, and now trackpad isn't working

Tags: battery, mouse, trackpad

I recently had my laptop break, it would not turn on. I brought it to the Apple Store and it was sent out and fixed, replacing the battery and the logic board. It worked fine when I got it back, but my trackpad wasn't clicking the way it used to. I have had it for less than two weeks now, and my trackpad has COMPLETELY stopped working. Luckily I had a USB mouse, where I could change the setting where I only have to touch the mouse as opposed to clicking it. Do you think this could be due to a swollen battery? (hope not since I got a new one 2 weeks ago) Or what else could it be due to?

Comment: Sounds to me like you should take it back to whoever fixed it. I'm surprised an actual Apple Store would allow that to be released back to you in such a state.